# How to manage the memory of data structures and heap of a virtual machine in plain C

Tags: c, memory-management, interpreter

In my interpreter I need to manage its runtime objects, along with its internal data structures.

I would want to create an interpreter in which there is no difference between the interpreter data structures (stack, symbol table) and the objects created by the user. I have seen this first in Little Smalltalk.

This way the interpreter looks like a tiny real machine, in respect to the interpreter structures living in the managed heap and all being of the same type (like the von Neumann architecture). I think this is the most cool and exciting way to write an interpreter.

But I would want to do a bit differently, creating the managed objects as C structs, and not arrays, like normally is done. The problem with C structs, arise when I would try to garbage collect or resize the heap. The pointers would be invalidated.

Somebody have figured on how to do this with pointers? I know this is pratically impossible, but somebody came near it?

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't gather enough to figure out what it is that you're asking.

Comment: I'm sorry even more! English is not my native language, sometimes when writting in english I scramble what I think to write. Gets +1!

Comment: Can't you use standard `malloc`, `realloc`, `free` for both "program heap" and "data structures"?

Comment: Ah! You want, perhaps, a [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) ... for C, I've heard some people talk about [Boehm-Demers-Weiser](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/)

Comment: Possibly memory pools may help you. Pool may be wiped from memory in single function call. Some c libs implementing it are exist.

Comment: I could use malloc, only if I dont find another option. I want the interpreter memory to be like of Little Smalltalk, which is closer to real machines, in respect to the interpreter data structures, which reside in the interpreter's heap memory.

Comment: @pmg: I have heard about it too, but its very platform dependent. I would need something more lightweight. @vovanium: memory pools can be a good option; I could use pools for the interpreter structures and heap objects. The code for each would be the same, with only a different function.

Answer (score 1):

Doug Lea wrote the basis for some of the malloc implementations out there, back in 1994.

You can download the public domain source:

```
http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, your help and of our friends are invaluable! +1

Answer (score 0):

I had similar concerns for my Postscript interpreter. Some discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.postscript/VsFzRwnuM_E/9PsgyVxS5-sJ).

The way I got around pointer invalidation is to have two *layers* of addressing. *Virtual* addresses, if you will.

The master data structure is allocated separately and has pointers to the base address, the maximum allocated size, and the currently used size. At address zero in the memory is the first *address table* which contains allocation sizes and base-offsets (integers, or "cursors", which when added to the base-pointer yield an actual C pointer to the data).

Since the interpreter is non-interrupting, operator functions need not worry about pointers becoming invalid during their execution, so the overhead of fetching the pointer from the handle (a table-index, the actual user *pointer*), need only happen once pointer fetched.

It seemed to work well in all tests. I got hung up later needing to optimize the inner loop.